# Error When Creating Pivot VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for some assistance.

I am facing an issue wen trying to create a pivot table in excel.

When I run the following code:

```
Sub Create_Pivot()


ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    Sheets("Data In Scope").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Address).CreatePivotTableTableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot For Data").Range("A1"), TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10


End Sub
```

I have no issue, but I require Pivot table Version 14 to be used.

When I add the following code:

```
Sub Create_Pivot()


ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    Sheets("Data In Scope").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Address).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot For Data").Range("A1"), TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14


End Sub
```

I get a Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or Argument

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

W

Answer (score 0):

You need to also specify the version when adding the PivotCache. You need to add:

```
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

to the parameter list in the Add Method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PivotCaches.Create` instead of the deprecated `PivotCaches.Add` method

```
Sub Create_Pivot()


ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    Sheets("Data In Scope").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("Pivot For Data").Range("A1"), TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14


End Sub
```